# How to use jquery validation in select option event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How to use jquery validation in select option event jquery?

In my script i try these.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name='slc_type']").change(function () {
        var ass_con = $(this).val();
        switch (ass_con) {
            case '1':
            case '4':
            case '7':
                $('#pc_detail').removeAttr("hidden");
                $('#printer_detail').prop('hidden', true);   
                $("#newasset_frm1").validate({
                    onkeyup: false,
                    onclick: false,
                    onfocusout: false,
                    rules: {
                        txt_fixasset: "required",
                        slc_condition: "required",
                        slc_type: "required",
                        slc_branch: "required",
                        slc_department: "required",
                        ass_description: "required",
                        slc_brand: "required",
                        slc_model: "required",
                        txt_servicetag: "required"
                    }
                });

                break;
            case '2':
            case '3':             
                $('#printer_detail').removeAttr("hidden");
                $('#pc_detail').prop('hidden', true);
                $("#newasset_frm1").validate({
                    onkeyup: false,
                    onclick: false,
                    onfocusout: false,
                    rules: {
                        txt_fixasset: "required",
                        slc_condition: "required",
                        slc_type: "required",
                        slc_branch: "required",
                        slc_department: "required",
                        ass_description: "required",
                        slc_brand: "required",
                        slc_address: "required",
                        txt_street: "required"
                    }
                });
                break;
        }              
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working when i am select on select option. It's not validate when i click on submit by not fill the requirement it's not validate.Any idea??

Comment: Please post the html too

Comment: The jQuery Validation Engine is not the same plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're trying to call `.validate()` based on a `select` element; and this does not make sense.  The `.validate()` method is only used to **initialize** the plugin on your form.
2. You're also trying to call `.validate()` attached to the same form with different parameters.  The `.validate()` method can only be called once, and all subsequent calls are ignored.  You cannot dynamically change the options once initialized.  One exception is the `.rules()` method(s), which allows you to dynamically change the rules.

The `.validate()` method should only be called once on the form when the form is created, typically on page load or page ready event.  Then within your `switch case` you can use the `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods to dynamically change the rules on your form.

See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/rules/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)

Comment: Thank you very much